# cppcms example for using session in asynchronous mode

Tags: c++, session, asynchronous, cppcms

cppcms website doesn't include an example about using sessions in asynchronous mode. How I can create an asynchronous session management system using cppcms?

**Added later:**
I used this code for saving a session:

```
session()["name"] = ...
session().save();
```

and somewhere I placed this:

```
if(!session().load() || !session().is_set("name"))
    std::cerr<<"error";
```

When I run program it shows error.
this is my config file (session section):

```
"expire": "renew",
"timeout": 604800,
"location": "both",
"client" : {
    "hmac": "sha1",
    "hmac_key": "...",
},
"server":{
    "storage": "files"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the section with heading "Now let's create our main asynchronous function", it does provide session and bind socket to session.
 http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_aio

Comment: Yes of course , see the following api reference http://cppcms.com/cppcms_ref/latest/classcppcms_1_1session__interface.html#details. You can also get the current session from context object.

Comment: session_interface& cppcms::http::context::session (  ) 
Get an interface to current session

Note, when using asynchronous CppCMS applications, session data is not fetched and is not updated, because session access may be not cheap, So when using session_interface in asynchronous application make sure you call session_inerface::load member function

Comment: Artyom has offered this link too as you can see. I tested load() but it didn't help. I will edit my question. Please see that and help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just read the manuals:

http://cppcms.com/cppcms_ref/latest/classcppcms_1_1session__interface.html#ae63e68dd2ec1d615f5a6a85bcee36605

You need to call `session().load()` before using session object.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I did it and got no result. nothing was loaded

Answer (score 0):

By default the session configuration is disabled. Please enable that first. See the following for reference. http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_config#session. After you have configured session. The rest is the same as I previously stated. Session management is described in detailed over here. http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/secure_programming